# Django Admin - populate other fields after changing foreignkey

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have this model:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(
        Client,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='orders',
        related_query_name='order',
    )

    delivery_country = CountryField('Kraj wysyłki', null=True, blank=True)
    delivery_city = models.CharField('Miasto wysyłki', max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    delivery_street = models.CharField('Ulica wysyłki', max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)

    billing_country = CountryField('Kraj dla faktury', null=True, blank=True)
    billing_city = models.CharField('Miasto dla faktury', max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    billing_street = models.CharField('Ulica dla faktury', max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)

    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product, through='OrderProduct')

class Client(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Imię', max_length=255)
    surname = models.CharField('Nazwisko', max_length=255)
    country = CountryField('Kraj', null=True, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField('Miasto', max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    street = models.CharField('Ulica', max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
```

And I would like to achieve this behaviour in Django Admin:
After every change of `Order.client` I want to prepopulate other fields like this:

- `Order.delivery_country = client.country`
- `Order.delivery_city = client.city`
- `Order.delivery_street = client.street`
- `Order.billing_country = client.country`
- `Order.billing_city = client.city`
- `Order.billing_street = client.street`

Is there any package/plugin to achieve this?
Or maybe you have some ideas how I could do it myself?

Comment: If the details of the order are literally the details of the client, why would you store the data in the order at all? Pull it directly from the `client` ForeignKey.

Comment: Also I disagree with you making the billing info the same as the shipping info, but that's a completely separate issue. What if I'm buying a gift for my friend or relative, and I want the order shipped to a different location than my billing info? What if I'm purchasing material for my business, but the billing location is at HQ and the parts should be shipped to another plant?

Comment: Unfortunately i need these two addresses. I can't take them from foreign key because client's address can change in future and I want to keep real delivery address in order. I need two addresses because sometimes company have one address to invoice and their warehouse is in different place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I achieved this:

## JS:

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("select[name='client']").on("change", function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: "/admin/clients/"+$(this).val(),
                type: "GET",
            }).done(function(data){
                client_data = $.parseJSON(data);
                client_data = client_data[0];

                $("select[name='delivery_country']").val(client_data.fields.country);
                $("input[name='delivery_city']").val(client_data.fields.city);
                $("input[name='delivery_street']").val(client_data.fields.street);

                $("select[name='billing_country']").val(client_data.fields.country);
                $("input[name='billing_city']").val(client_data.fields.city);
                $("input[name='billing_street']").val(client_data.fields.street);
            });
        });
    });
})(django.jQuery);
```

## And View:

```
def get_client_ajax(request, id):
    return JsonResponse(serializers.serialize('json', Client.objects.filter(id=id)), safe=False)
```